# Layer 2 error correction

Tags: layer2, errors

How are acknowledgement sent at data link layer to the sender when crc of frame is incorrect?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

> How are acknowledgement sent at data link layer to the sender when crc
>   of frame is incorrect?

That depends on the Data-Link protocol, but most Data-Link protocols simply drop bad frames. For example, if an ethernet device receives a frame with a bad FCS, the hardware simply discards the frame, and it never reaches the Data-Link layer.

Also, most Data-Link protocols do not perform any type of acknowledgement. They are connectionless protocols that send out a frame, and they do not care that the frame is damaged or dropped.

Comment: But ARQ or Stop and wait sends NACK  if the data was not received. How does it tell the sender which frame to send again since there is no sequencing in frames?

Comment: You are talking about transport-layer protocols, like TCP. Data-Link protocols are like ethernet, frame relay, Wi-Fi, ATM. PPP, token ring, ARCNET, etc.

Comment: But data link layer uses flow control methods like ALQ. They send ack or nack according to the situation. How they do it?

Comment: No, they don't. In the real world, what we answer of here, Data-Link protocols are connectionless, as is IP. TCP, a Transport-layer protocol, is connection-oriented, and it uses ACKs. Ethernet and Wi-Fi interfaces are what you get on the PC, printers, laptops, etc., and those, which are series of Physical and a Data-Link protocols , have no such thing as you describe. I have no idea where you are getting your ideas.

Comment: So if CRC check fails then that frame will be dropped. But what will the sender do about that?

Comment: The sender is completely unaware that happened. It is up to the upper-layer protocols, e.g. TCP, to notice that something is missing and request it to be resent, or, in the case of UDP and other connectionless protocols, the application must notice that something is missing and ask for it to be resent.

Comment: Ok, I got it now. Thanks. Can you suggest me some good books on networking in deep??

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic for SE sites, except [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se]. People have suggested other sites for SE, but SE has decided it wants no more recommendations: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24050/122193